# logging out in php ( cookies and sessions )

Tags: php, session, cookies

i have written  login and logout scripts in php.I am able to log in but log out is not working.Someone please point the mistake.i am completely lost.Here's the complete code.

1.the log in php code:

```
    <?php
session_start();
require_once('login/connectvars.php');
$msg = "";

if(!isset($_SESSION['username']) && isset($_COOKIE['username']))
{
    $_SESSION['username'] = $_COOKIE['username'];
}

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    $dbc = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD,DB_NAME);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['username']));
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($dbc,trim($_POST['password']));

    if(!empty($username) && !empty($password))
    {
        $query = "SELECT username FROM users_dns WHERE username = '$username' AND password = SHA('$password')";
        $data = mysqli_query($dbc,$query) or die(mysqli_error($dbc));

        if(mysqli_num_rows($data) == 1)
        {
            $row = mysqli_fetch_array($data);
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
            setcookie('username',$row['username'],time()+(60*6));
            $msg = 'success';
        }
        else
        {
            $msg = 'enter correct values..';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $msg = 'Enter all fields..';
    }
}

?>
```

2.the code i used in HTML to check the session.

```
   <div id="login_form">
          <h2>
            <?php echo $msg; ?>
          </h2>
       <?php
       if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
        {
            echo 'nothing<br />';
            echo '<a href="login/logout.php">log out'.$_SESSION['username'].'</a><br />';
        }
        else
        {
       ?>
         <form id="login"  method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
            <table>
                  <tr>
                     <th>Username:</th>
                     <th>Password:</th>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                     <td><input type="text" name="username" /></td>
                     <td><input type="password" name="password" /></td>
                   </tr>
                   <tr>
                      <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In" class="submit" /></td>
                      <td><a href="login/signup.php"><input type="button" class="submit" value="Sign Up" /></a></td>
                   </tr>
            </table>
         </form>
         <?php
         }
         ?>
    <!-- login form -->

   </div>
```

3.The logout script

```
    <?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['username']))
{
    $_SESSION = array();

    if(isset($_COOKIE[session_name()]))
    {
        setcookie(session_name(),'',time() - 3600);
    }
    session_destroy();
}

setcookie('username','',time() - 3600);

echo 'redirecting you...please wait..';
header("Refresh: 3;url=http://localhost/");
?>
```

Comment: why do you do this? `$_SESSION = array();` ? and you should just use `setcookie('username', '', time()-1);`

Comment: I used it so that all session variables are destroyed..

Comment: don't do that... just use `session_destroy()`, as for the cookies, you should use `print_r($_COOKIE)` to see who's left and why

Comment: i removed `$_SESSION = array();` But it's still not logging out.
And the `print_r($_COOKIE)` is showing a lot of information which i am not able to understand

Comment: just post it here, unless you have some passwords stored in cookies

Comment: this is what `print_r($_COOKIE)` is showing...

`Array
(
    [__utma] => 111872281.880081607.1359012805.1359046960.1359096568.4
    [__utmz] => 111872281.1359012805.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none)
    [__utmb] => 111872281.93.10.1359096568
    [PHPSESSID] => o6if69moddunjlqh30q2ckpvg2
    [__utmc] => 111872281
    [username] => a
)`

Comment: try deleting all your cookies and try your login-logout script again.

Comment: oh god..still not working...
deleted all cookies but same problem..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For deleting all cookies try.

```
<?php

if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']))
{
    $cookies = explode(';', $_SERVER['HTTP_COOKIE']);
    foreach($cookies as $cookie)
    {
        $mainCookies = explode('=', $cookie);
        $name = trim($mainCookies[0]);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000);
        setcookie($name, '', time()-1000, '/');
    }
}
```

And for `session` you need to learn more about `ob_start(); and ob_flush();`.
Cheers.

Comment: its loops through cookies that are set and just set those cookies time in past one by one..thats the trick...cheers..

Comment: To delete a cookie you just set the cookie again but with expired time.

Comment: +1 for you to asking about answer...and why answer written this way...its good to hear that you just don't want answer but also want to learn it...good...+1 +1 +1 +1 +1 for u...

Comment: Thanks a lot.It's encouraging.And one more thing.
is it possible to shorten this code a little..because i am not yet very good at php..so a little lesser code will make me feel better..!!

Comment: need to spend time for shorting this code but this is the best way for now...will update you with more alternative shortly...

Answer (score 0):

For logout just use :

```
session_destroy();
header('Location: index.php'); // file name where you want to redirect after logout
exit();
```

Comment: But there is also a COOKIE created which needs to be destroyed..??